# how to set expire of jwt when using jjwt

Tags: java, jwt

Now I am using this code to generate a JWT token and set an expire time in my project:

```
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(jwtSignKey.getBytes(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getJcaName());
        JwtPayload jwtPayload = new JwtPayload();
        jwtPayload.setUserId(user.getId());
        jwtPayload.setDeviceId(request.getDeviceId());
        jwtPayload.setAppId(Long.valueOf(request.getApp().getKey()));
        byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(JSON.toJSONString(jwtPayload).getBytes());
        String accessToken = Jwts.builder().setPayload(new String(bytesEncoded))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30*1000))
                .signWith(secretKey).compact();
```

but it tell me:

```
Both 'payload' and 'claims' cannot both be specified. Choose either one.
```

then what should I do to set a expire time with the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

playload and claim should choose one of then, `setExpiration` belong claim, so just tweak code like this:

```
 public static String generateAccessToken(String jwtSignKey, JwtPayload jwtPayload) {
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(jwtSignKey.getBytes(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getJcaName());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map claims = objectMapper.convertValue(jwtPayload, Map.class);
        String accessToken = Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 1000))
                .signWith(secretKey).compact();
        return accessToken;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/latest/io/jsonwebtoken/JwtBuilder.html#setPayload(java.lang.String)), Payload must be a plaintext (NON-JSON) String. You could try base64 encoding that value or possibly creating a Claims via `Jwts.claims()`

Can you detail what you are aiming to do?

Comment: I want to generate an access token and set an expire time of this token.@Dave G